# Modify or Replace the Facebook like button flyout box

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

I have a project with a client strongly preferring the Facebook 'Share' button over the 'like' button. I need to slightly modify 'like' to convince them to use it. I am well aware that the 'Share' button is deprecated (and has problems because of it), but they've been quite insistent.

Something they seem to prefer, apart from the button's verbage, is the 'share' button popup window that also allows the user to change the default text (provided by Facebook's open graph tags, i.e. og:description, etc.) by clicking on it.

Maybe they can be moved to use the 'like' button if it can function somewhat more like 'share'. Is it possible to somehow get that 'like' button flyout dialog (that appears when you click the button and has the og:title, og:image, og:description, etc. tags) to appear in a popup window? Preferably with the ability for the user to change that text by clicking it, as the 'share' popup allows?

They also want the counter, otherwise I'd just use css with my anchor tag below.

I've tried the following, but with no luck on the 'like' button. Google will be replaced with my site and its own og tags:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

    <head></head>

    <body>

        <div id="fb-root"></div>
         <script>

          function share() {
             FB.ui({
                 method: 'stream.share',
                 u: 'www.google.com',
              });
          };

          (function(d, s, id) {
              var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
              if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
              js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
              js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
              fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
          }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        </script>

        <fb:like id="fbLike" href="www.google.com" onclick="share();" send="false" layout="box_count" show_faces="false" ></fb:like>

        <a href="#/" onclick="share();">Can I get the like button to work like this?</a>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use feed dialog to share on users wall. Is there any particular reason for not using it which i am missing out?.

The code for invoking feed dialog will be something like this :

```
     function share() {
        FB.ui({
        method: ‘feed’,
        link: ‘link of where the user should land when he click on post goes here’,
        picture: ‘picture url goes here’,
        name: ‘Name goes here’,
        caption: ‘Caption goes here e.g www.google.com’,
        description: ‘description goes here’}, 
        function (response) {
                      if (!response || response.error) {
                    //When posting fails
                      } else {
                    //When posting succeeds
          }
    );
}
```

You can find more details here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think anyone would answer after I'd had this posted for almost a week. Thanks for the suggestion, but with the feed dialog, the link that you attach the feed method to doesn't have a counter, and the default text in the feed dialog can't be edited by the user. The wording on the button would work, and I do like that this type of 'share' is supported.

In the end, we just wound up using the deprecated share button. And it's functionality seems to occasionally do weird things and/or break and then fix itself as Facebook updates their js. Oh well, people want what they want...

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that nobody has a workaround. I guess if somebody finds my anchor example useful to create a custom share button (even though it's deprecated - seriously, unless you're in my boat, help yourself out and just use like), at least my problem's helped somebody out. I've found that adding:

```
    style="overflow:hidden"
```

to the fb:like tag, and then adding the following code to the beginning of the script block (just before the share function):

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: ''
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
            share();
        });
    };
```

will hide the like dialog, and use the share popup when the user clicks the like button (the edge.create listens for the user like action). The problem, though, is that the user will then have two posts on the user's wall - one for the like action, and another for the share. With both posting, as expected, the same open graph tag title, image, and description information, only with one post saying they 'liked' and the other saying they 'shared'. But I'd need to prevent the 'like' one. And the counter will, of course, increment by 2. Close, but not quite good enough.

Any way to just make the like dialog box appear in a popup window?